# Cant connect using imap_open to peoplepc.com mail server

Tags: php, email, ssl, imap, imap-open

Im just having trouble getting connected to peoplepc.com webmail via imap , 
Here is the code :

```
    $host  = "{imap.peoplepc.com:143/imap}";
    $user  = "User@peoplepc.com";
    $pass  = "Password";
    try {
        $mbox = imap_open($host, $user, $pass) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
        if ( $mbox==true) {

           //do this

        } else {
           //do this instead

        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
       //handle exception 

    }
```

please can you show me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Define "having trouble". Also, I see you've tagged the question with 'ssl' but you're neither using the `/ssl` flag or connecting to the IMAP SSL port, 993.

Comment: Actually, I just poked the server. They don't support SSL, but they do support TLS. So use port 143 and the `/tls` flag.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response 

sorry abt the confusion, im new here :)

I used  "{imap.peoplepc.com:143/imap/tls}" and i still get the same error 
can't connect: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

Comment: Sounds like a connection issue. Can you ping the server, and are you behind a firewall that might be filtering outbound traffic? eg: an office firewall may well block outbound connections to mail services for security purposes.